# Simulating Momentum in a Game Engine

Tags: python, game-physics

Just for fun, I've been working on a simple platformer engine in Pygame over break.  Today I tried to add some momentum code so that the player doesn't instantly stop, but I've been running into a problem.  My momentum code does not slow the player down at a constant rate over all possible FPS rates.  Here is my code:

```
def getXDisplacement(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dt = self.xTimer.elapsedTime()
        self.momentum = self.momentum * ( (1-self.momentumDecayRate) ** dt)
        self.xDisplacement = ((self.rightKey.ifActive(pressed)-self.leftKey.ifActive(pressed)) + self.momentum)    
        self.momentum = self.xDisplacement
        self.xDisplacement *= dt
        self.xDisplacement = numpy.clip(self.xDisplacement, -700*dt, 700*dt)
        self.xTimer.reset()
```

To slow down the FPS, I'll add a `print()` function to the top of the `getXDisplacement()` function.  I also comment out the `numpy.clip()` function towards the bottom to see how total speed is affected.  With a slower FPS rate, the player accelerates much more slowly and doesn't quite reach the same speed as at higher FPS rates.  I can't imagine why an exponential decay function wouldn't work here.  Am I using it improperly, or is the problem more complicated than I think?  For reference, here is the link to the full program: https://github.com/2Amateurs/SimplePygamePlatformer.

Comment: If your game might run in different FPS, you should bind your computations with the system clock, rather than computing a formula every frame. I would recommand you to use precomputed values for location and speed, and do interpolation on these values based on time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pygame clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) to limit the maximum FPS:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# in your game loop
while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

If you're certain your game won't run slower than say 30 FPS, this is already sufficient. If not, you can use the clock to calculate the delta time between the last and this frame.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# in your game loop
while True:
    delta_time = clock.tick_busy_loop()
    getXDisplacement(delta_time)

def getXDisplacement(self, dt):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.momentum = self.momentum * ( (1-self.momentumDecayRate) ** dt)
        self.xDisplacement = ((self.rightKey.ifActive(pressed)-self.leftKey.ifActive(pressed)) + self.momentum)    
        self.momentum = self.xDisplacement
        self.xDisplacement *= dt
        self.xDisplacement = numpy.clip(self.xDisplacement, -700*dt, 700*dt)
```

`tick_busy_loop` is not the only way, also take a look at [Clock.get_time](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.get_time).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
The pygame clock.tick() function sometimes slows down my projects when the code is doing something that requires more than the average amount of time per frame.  Generally, I've found that keeping the FPS unbounded works best for making the game smooth.  Also, I already have a method to calculate the delta time between frames: I made my own Timer class that uses the system clock to count elapsed time.  My problem is not how to count time accurately, but how to use that to achieve constant change in momentum over change in time no matter the current FPS.